# Necesito pasar una fecha en formato decimal a milisegundos

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

Tengo que hacer una app para un trabajo del grado, en ella me pide hacer una lista de eventos, en la que para crear los eventos necesito una fecha. En vez de usar un date picker me complique y he usado un dialogo que me saca un date picker dialog.La fecha la meto en textView en formato digital, pero necesito sacar sus milisegundos para ordenar la lista en función del tiempo.

El problema viene que al crear el calendario, que lo llamo c, no puedo hacer:

```
public void calendar() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        //milisegundos=c.getTimeInMillis();
        dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            }
        }, year, month, day);

    }
```

porque los milisegundos que coge son los de la fecha y hora actual

por otro lado la fecha la hago text view asi:

```
fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dpd.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int month1, int dayOfMonth) {
                        day = dayOfMonth;
                        month = month1;
                        year = year1;

                        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00");
                        String date= format.format(Double.valueOf(dayOfMonth))+"/"+format.format(Double.valueOf(month+1))+"/"+format.format(Double.valueOf(year));
                        String myDate =date;

                       c.getTimeInMillis();



                        fecha.setText(date);
                    }
                });
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
```

Entonces, lo que me gustaría hacer es coger ese formato decimal de la fecha y pasarlo a milisegundo, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo o si se puede si quiera. Si pudiesen ayudarme a arreglar esto lo agradecería, no quiero poner un date picker asi sin mas,me gusta mucho mas asi. Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes la fecha: *10 de Junio del 2012*, la puedes tener en los siguientes formatos:

1. En **String**: 10.06.12  ó 10/06/2012, para este formato se utiliza el método SimpleDateFormat.
2. En **Date**: Lun Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT 2012, es de tipo String y así viene por default, aunque con los métodos SimpleDateFormat    y
       DateTimeFormatter lo personalizas
3. En **Millis** ó milisegundos: 1339286400000, es de tipo long.

Dentro del método `onDateSet`, la fecha que seleccionaste en el picker la conviertes al formato que quieras (visualizalo en un textView):

```
c.set(year, month, day);         //seteas la fecha del Calendar que obtuviste con el picker
long enMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();    // calendar lo conviertes a millis
//textView.setText(" "+enMillis);  // ó textView.setText(""+c.getTimeInMillis());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");  // para "verlo" así: 10.06.12
String fecha = sdf.format(c.getTime());
//textView.setText(fecha);

Date d = c.getTime();      // Date con su formato por default: Lun Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT 2012
//textView.setText(d.toString); // ó textView.setText(c.getTime().toString());

DateFormat otroformato = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a", new Locale("es", "ES"));  // Date con formato personalizado y en español
String formattedDate = otroformato.format(d);
//textView.setText(formattedDate);

LocalDateTime ldt= LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());       // usando LocalDateTime
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a", new Locale("es", "ES"));
String formattedDateTime = dateTimeFormatter.format(ldt);
//textView.setText(formattedDateTime);
```

Entonces el Calendar con `getTime()` obtienes el Date y con `getTimeInMillis()` obtienes los milisegundos.

Si una fecha fue ingresada manualmente (`String`) y quieres pasarla a `Date`, tienes que usar un `try/catch`:

```
    String fechaManual = "10/01/2020";
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();

    try {
        date = sd.parse(fechaManual);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
   //textView.setText(date.toString);
```

`Date` lo puedes convertir a `milisegundos` así:

```
    long milisegs = date.getTime();
    textView.setText("Date en Millis: "+milisegs);
```